# Drupal 6 site importing with lack of data

Tags: 6, database, migrations

I'm assigned to do some theming tasks on existing site, but had problem setting up site locally. I was provided with sites `files` and `sites/design` folder which consist of `settings.php`,`modules`,`themes`. I created a multi-site structure. I was also provided with one database file `d6_design.sql`. Apparently, this site is based on `d6_design` database and also sync data from other website which use database `d6_liaa`. So the thing is, when I launch site locally I get an error `Table d6_liaa.users does not exist.` and some other errors related to `d6_liaa` database. The main content is seems to be stored on `d6_design` database, but `users` and other tables from `d6_liaa` database. So my question is if the provided data is enough to launch the site locally and if yes, then what's wrong with my setup or `settings.php` file and I can't create connection with the site database, otherwise am I supposed to have database `d6_liaa`. The following is provided `settings.php` content adjusted to my localhost settings. Also after setting up page and seeing table not found error hitting the refresh page button everything just crashes and `Page is not available`. In `settings.php` file I can see that some kind of connection is declared to `d6_liaa` database, but is that meant locally or by accessing site.

```
<?php
$db_url = 'mysql://root@localhost/d6_design';

$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/cacherouter/cacherouter.inc';
$conf['cacherouter'] = array(
   'default' => array(
    'engine' => 'apc',
    'servers' => array(),
    'shared' => TRUE,
    'prefix' => 'design',
    'static' => FALSE,
    'fast_cache' => TRUE,
  ),
);

$db_prefix = array(
'default' => '',
'users' => 'd6_liaa.',
'sessions' => 'd6_liaa.',
'authmap' => 'd6_liaa.',
'profile_fields' => 'd6_liaa.',
'profile_values' => 'd6_liaa.',
'drconnect_users' => 'd6_liaa.',
'fbconnect_users' => 'd6_liaa.',
'linkedin_token'  => 'd6_liaa.',
'twitter_account'  => 'd6_liaa.',
);

$conf['install_profile'] = 'd6_liaa';
$conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'design';
$conf['site_name']         = '';

$conf['insert_absolute_paths'] = FALSE;

/**TRANSLATABLE VARIABLES */
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array(
  'site_name',
  'site_slogan',
  'site_mission',
  'site_footer',
  'anonymous',
  'menu_primary_menu',
  'menu_secondary_menu',
  'contact_form_information',
  'user_mail_password_reset_body',
  'user_mail_password_reset_subject',
  'user_mail_register_admin_created_body',
  'user_mail_register_admin_created_subject',
  'user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body',
  'user_mail_register_no_approval_required_subject',
  'user_mail_register_pending_approval_body',
  'user_mail_register_pending_approval_subject',
  'user_mail_status_activated_body',
  'user_mail_status_activated_subject',
  'user_mail_status_blocked_body',
  'user_mail_status_blocked_subject',
  'user_mail_status_deleted_body',
  'user_mail_status_deleted_subject',
  'user_picture_guidelines',
  'user_registration_help',
);

$update_free_access = FALSE;

ini_set('arg_separator.output',     '&amp;');
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime',     0);
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase',      0);
ini_set('session.cache_expire',     200000);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter',    'none');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  0);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',   200000);
ini_set('session.save_handler',     'user');
ini_set('session.use_cookies',      1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid',    0);
ini_set('url_rewriter.tags',        '');

ini_set ("session.auto_start", 0);
```